# Sending someone a Link in Outlook that refers to a local application with a param

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook, hyperlink

I want to send someone a HTML Mail via my application (c#). This Mail contains should contain a clickable html link that refers to a local application. f.e. :

```
<a href="c:\myapplication.exe -1234">click</a>
```

It already works to send the mail but the link does not appear as a link. I also tried the "file:/// ... " thing but it does not work in combination with a param.

Does someone know another solution ?

Comment: I would hope that this doesn't work.  Here, open my email and click on my disguised link which scans your hard drive and sends me any credit card numbers it finds and, oh, by the way installs a bot on the system that lets me access it any time I want.

Comment: It just doesn't work that way - you cannot invoke executables on the local filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Security this does not work.